# selenium jre1.7 and 1.8 compatibility conflict

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

[image]
Anyone pls help me out with this.

I am using jre 1.8 with eclipse indigo for my windows7 32 bit os.I was actually trying to do selenium automation, but it is showing this exception even though the code is correct. I did set java compiler version to 1.6 in project build path also. And when i use jre 1.8 sendKeys() method doen't work, if i use jre 1.7 sendkeys() method woeks but major minor version 52.0 exception occurs.what to do?

package com.testing;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\geckodriver-v0.25.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='identifierId']"));
        ele.sendKeys("cheethaisyours");
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen in two scenarios.

1) Testing is pre-compiled using compiler of Java 8 and run in Java 6 Environment. Make sure JDK version in Eclipse and JRE are same. This is can be potential cause.

2) JAR files needs to be changed accordingly depending on the version of Java. If you are going to use a JAR file with minimum requirement of Java 8, this would give you a similar error. You will need to change all your JAR files as well when you change the JDK.